# Двусвязный список. Сортировка. Не срабатывает своп

Tags: c++, сортировка, двусвязный-список

Первый раз написал простую сортировку двусвязного списка. Вроде в функции Sort() всё работает. Решил отдельно сделать функцию Swap(Node*, Node*), и что-то она не срабатывает. Вроде внутри Swap обмен адресов происходит норм, а когда возвращается в Sort, то не норм :). Посмотрите пожалуйста код, где ошибка?

```
void List::Swap(Node* a, Node* b)
{
     Node* tmp = a;
     tmp->prev = a->prev;
     a = b;
     a->prev = tmp->prev;
     tmp->next = b->next;   
     //b->next->prev = tmp;
     b = tmp;
     b->prev = a;
     a->next = b;
 }

 void List::Sort()
 {
     if(!head)
     {
       std::cout<<"\nСписок пуст!"<<std::endl;
       return;
     }
    bool flag;
    Node* tmp = NULL;
    Node*  begin = NULL;
    Node* beginNext = NULL; 
    Node* first = NULL;

   for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
       flag = false;

   for(Node* node = head; node; node = node->next)   
   {
       if(node->next && node->val > node->next->val)
       {             
          this->Swap(node, node->next);
         //здесь обмен адресов работает
          /*tmp = node;
          tmp->prev = node->prev;
          node = node->next;
          node->prev = tmp->prev;
          tmp->next = node->next;   
          tmp->prev = node;
          node->next = tmp;*/         

       }

         if(!flag)
         {
             begin = node;
             first = begin;
             flag = true; 
         }
        else
        {
              beginNext = node;
              beginNext->prev = first;
              first->next = beginNext;
              first = first->next;
              beginNext = beginNext->next;                   
        }
           if(!node->next)
              tail = node;          
   }//for2
   head = begin;     
 }//for1
```

}

Comment: Данные копируются в функцию swap.

Comment: по указателям же

Comment: Написана какая-то бессмыслица в обоих случаях. `tmp = node; tmp->prev = node->prev;`. В чем смысл `tmp->prev = node->prev`, если заведомо `tmp == node`???

Comment: на всякий случай. это тест. я только учусь

Comment: Я имел в виду что данные надо свапить (копировать) в функции свап, а не сами `Node`, что правильней. Например `tmp = Node1->val ; Node1->val = Node2->val; Node2->val = tmp;`

Comment: Вам надо определиться, что вы хотите свапить - указатели, или содержимое структур, на которые они указывают.

Comment: @VTT, Смысл свапить пустые структуры? Просто лишние телодвижения, в LinkedList речь по любому идёт о данных в структурах.

Comment: @VTT указатели свапить

Comment: Ну тогда будет `Swap(Node * & a, Node * & b) {auto tmp{b}; b = a; a = tmp; }`

Comment: @VTT Попробовал ваш код - [Error] cannot convert 'std::initializer_list<Node*>' to 'Node*' in assignment. Я новичок, поэтому не знаю в чём ошибка. Конструктор rкопирования наверное нужен?

Comment: Похоже что у вас древний компилятор, или некорректно настроена сборка. Попробуйте тогда `Node * tmp(b);`

Answer (score 2):

```
void List::Swap(Node* a, Node* b)
{
```

указатель    `a` содержит адрес некого обьекта x1( указывает на x1 ) ,  а указатель `b` адрес обьекта `x2`(указывет на x2)

```
     Node* tmp = a;
```

это означает, что и `tmp` и `a` указывают на x1, поэтому:

```
     tmp->prev = a->prev;
```

лишнее, поскольку и левое и правое выражения есть одно и то же

```
     a = b;
     a->prev = tmp->prev;
```

тут вы вообше ввели путаницу: `a` уже указывет на `х2`,  его элементу `prev` 
 вы присваиваете значение, что имеет `prev` обьекта `х1`, тем самым `prev` двух обьектов содержат одни и те же адреса... Дальше аналогичные ошибки:

```
     tmp->next = b->next;   
     //b->next->prev = tmp;
     b = tmp;
     b->prev = a;
     a->next = b;
 }
```

На самом деле, если вы хотите свапить указатели, то нужно просто:

```
 Node* tmp = a;
 a = b;
 b = tmp;
```

Но для альгоритма сортировки   нужно свапить обьекты, а не указатели:

```
*a = *b;
*b = *tmp;
```

Comment: Да, я понял, что  написал много лишнего. В вашем коде указатели не меняются, спасибо.

Comment: При этом сортировки не произойдет, поскольку а и б поменяться местами в памяти, а не по привязкам `а->некст` и `б->некст` и по ссылкам на них, в других пограничных элементах. Это про последний пример, со свапом указателей.

Comment: Адреса остаются на месте после выхода из функции. Может указатели  копируются в свопе?

Comment: На самом деле, свапить надо то что сортируете. Если контейнеры `Ноде` то по какому принципу? Вероятно по данным в них, вывод, надо свапить данные в них. И не трогать контейнеры, они стоят на нужных местах :)

Comment: @NewView,  тут я полностью согласен, но я добавлю в ответе еще одно предложение...

Comment: Свапить содержимое объектов почти всегда неправильно. Я даже не говорю про эффективность, если данных в элементе списка много.  Что будет если еще где-то в программе есть ссылки на эти данные?

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял и вы хотите в самом деле упорядочить двусвязный список, меняя указатели в структурах, то для вот такого элемента списка:

```
struct node {
  struct node *next,
    *prev;
  int v;
};
```

функция перестановки 2-х элементов (с учетом того, что мы ***всегда переставляем соседние элементы***)  должна выглядеть примерно так:

```
void
swap_nbrs (struct node *first, struct node *second, struct node **head)
{
  struct node *pp = first->prev, // элемент перед первым из переставляемой пары
    *lp = second->next;  // элемент после пары

  // переставим элементы
  second->prev = first->prev;
  first->next = second->next;
  first->prev = second;
  second->next = first;

  // скорректируем указатель на начало переставленной пары
  if (pp)
    pp->next = second;
  else
    *head = second; // пара была первой в списке, корректируем указатель на весь список

  if (lp) // корректируем элемент списка после пары
    lp->prev = first;      
}
```

Сама сортировка списка:

```
  struct node *list = make_list();

  int swaps;
  do {
    swaps = 0;
    for (struct node *p = list; p && p->next;)
      if (p->v > p->next->v)
        swap_nbrs(p, p->next, &list), ++swaps;
      else
        p = p->next;
  } while (swaps);
```

Если учесть, что мы всегда переставляем соседние элементы, то вот такая реализация функции перестановки соседей:

```
void
swap_p (struct node *first, struct node **head)
{
  if (first->next == 0)
    return;

  struct node *second = first->next,
    *pp = first->prev,
    *lp = second->next;

  second->prev = first->prev;
  first->next = second->next;
  first->prev = second;
  second->next = first;

  if (pp)
    pp->next = second;
  else
    *head = second;

  if (lp)
    lp->prev = first;
}
```

пожалуй, выглядит более логично.

**Update**

Для более общего случая, перестановки 2-х произвольных элементов двусвязного списка с вот таким заголовком (указатели на первый и последний элементы):

```
struct list2 {
  struct node *head, *tail;
};
```

можно использовать следующий код:

```
static void  // вспомогательная функция перестановки соседних элементов
swap_p (struct node *first, struct list2 *list)
{
  struct node *second = first->next,
    *before = first->prev,
    *after = second->next;

  second->prev = first->prev;
  first->next = second->next;
  first->prev = second;
  second->next = first;

  if (before)
    before->next = second;
  else
    list->head = second;

  if (after)
    after->prev = first;
  else
    list->tail = first;
}

void
swap_2 (struct list2 *list, struct node *a, struct node *b)
{
  if (a == b)  return;
  if (a->next == b) { swap_p(a, list); return; }
  if (b->next == a) { swap_p(b, list); return; }

  struct node *pa = a->prev, *na = a->next,
    *pb = b->prev, *nb = b->next;

#define SETL(e, e_link, ngbr, ngbr_link, list_ptr) do { \
    if (e->e_link = ngbr)               \
      ngbr->ngbr_link = e;              \
    else                                \
      list_ptr = e;                     \
  } while (0)


  SETL(a, next, nb, prev, list->tail);
  /* макрос разворачивается в такой код
    if (a->next = nb)
      nb->prev = a;
    else
      list->tail = a;
  */
  SETL(a, prev, pb, next, list->head);
  SETL(b, next, na, prev, list->tail);
  SETL(b, prev, pa, next, list->head);
#undef SETL  
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за пример

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то вот:

```
 void List::Swap(Node* a, Node* b) {
         Node* tmp = a->prev, tmp2 = b->next;
         tmp->next = b;
         b->prev = tmp;
         b->next = a;

         a->prev = b;
         a->next = tmp2;
         tmp2->prev = a;
 }
```

Comment: А что будет с первым (`a->prev == NULL`) и последним (`b->next == NULL`) элементами списка?

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему так(может кому пригодится :) После обмена вернул указатель обратно в Sort().

```
Node* List::Swap(Node* a, Node* b)
{
     Node* tmp = a;
     a = b;
     a->prev = tmp->prev;
     tmp->next = b->next;   
     b = tmp;
     b->prev = a;
     a->next = b;

  return a;
}

if(node->next && node->val > node->next->val)           
   node = this->Swap(node, node->next);
.........
```

Answer (score 0):

Только что написал вот это

```
d_node *xnode, *temp2;

        list = head;//ищем x
        for (int i = 0; i < x - 1; i++)
        {
            if (list->next)list = list->next;
        }
        xnode = list;//сохраняем X

        list = head;//ищем y
        for (int i = 0; i < y - 1; i++)
        {
            if (list->next)list = list->next;
        }//оставляем его висеть под названием list

        if (list->next)swap(list->next->prev, xnode->next->prev); //если учатвует не последний елемент меняем оба указатаеля
        else xnode->next->prev = list;//иначе заменяем лишь сущестующее значение

        swap(list->next, xnode->next);//в любом случае меняем

        if (xnode->prev)swap(list->prev->next, xnode->prev->next);//если участвует не первый елемент ...
        else { list->prev->next = xnode; head = list; } // иначе... + сохраняем новое начало списка

        swap(list->prev, xnode->prev);//в любом случае меняем
```

По заданию нужно было чтобы поменять два заданных с клавиатура элемента местами, все случаи учтены (надеюсь). Если умеешь,надеюсь умеешь... сократи. =)